# How to Avoid LineBreaks in Winforms TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Im learning c# at the moment, and I would like to add text to a TextBox.
I am appending Text with TextBox.AppendText() method:

```
 public delegate void WriteToLogEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
 private void WriteToLog(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
            Invoke(new WriteToLogEventHandler(WriteToLog), new object[] { sender, e });
        else
        {
            textBox_Messages.AppendText((e as WriteToLogEventArgs).Message);
        }

    }
```

But I don't want the Lines to automatic line break, I want the TextBox to scroll horizontal. I already tried the TextBox Scrollbar Property "vertical", "horizontal" and "both"

but the Textbox looks always like this:

[image]

Is there a way to automatically make the textbox horizontal scrollable

*excuse my english*
Thanks Locke...

Comment: `textBox_Messages.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;`

Comment: turn off multi-line if it's on.. also stretch the width of the textbox so that it's wide enough to show the text on a single line this appears to be common sense ..

Comment: nether `ScrollBars.Both` alone nor making it Multiline set to false worked. The Solution from @Fabio and @Thorsten Dittmar worked for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `WordWrap` property to `false` along with having both scroll bars.

Answer (score 1):

```
TextBox.WordWrap = false
```

From MSDN:

> **true** if the multiline text box control wraps words; **false** if the text
>   box control automatically scrolls horizontally when the user types
>   past the right edge of the control. The default is true.